# WebDriverManager: Can not get Resolution cache to work with CLI

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, command-line-interface, webdrivermanager-java

I am using WebDriverManager fat jar ver 5.0.3. I want to achieve following with CLI

1. Drivers are downloaded in a specified folder
2. Using Resolution Cache only download drivers if browser version changes, otherwise skip download

I am using following on command line:

`java -D'wdm.forceDownload=false' -D'wdm.resolutionCachePath="C:\QA\Downloads"' -jar webdrivermanager-5.0.3-fat.jar resolveDriverFor chrome`

I am able to achieve part-1 with this but resolution cache is always empty and driver is only updated when I delete it from download folder. Driver is not updated for part-2 of my requirement if there is a previous copy in the download folder.

can someone please help? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `wdm.cachePath` for that, and I think the quotes are not required:

```
java -Dwdm.forceDownload=false -Dwdm.cachePath=C:\QA\Downloads -jar webdrivermanager-5.0.3-fat.jar resolveDriverFor chrome
```